# linux-headers-$(uname -r) installer but /usr/include/ is not update with new headers

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, header

I am trying to develop a Linux Kernel Module, hence I need linux headers.

I installed the appropriate headers (`linux-headers-4.19.0-10-amd64`) with the following lines, but I do not know how to install them in `/usr/include/`

```
apt-get install -y vim mlocate tree openssh-server gdb libjsoncpp-dev apache2 libmariadbclient-dev libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev libcunit1-dev libgtk2.0-dev screen python perl sudo dos2unix gperf bison flex pkg-config llvm git sudo build-essential wget fuse cmake makedev  libgl1-mesa-dev  freeglut3-dev  libglu1-mesa-dev
apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
apt-get install -y linux-headers-generic
```

What is the correct form to update the `/usr/include` references ?

Answer (score 0):

Headers are to be found in `/usr/src` and not `/usr/include`.

Hence, it is not surprising that you don't find any reference to your headers in `/usr/include`

If you compile modules from a classical kernel, your headers should already be installed. If you compile from a custom kernel, `make headers_install` should do the trick.

Comment: when i execute: make headers_install i receive the message scripts/Makefile.build:45: scripts/basic/Makefile: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente